# Genesis Flood Compared/Contrasted with Atrahasis & Gilgamesh?

Tags: history, textual-criticism, noah, flood

Being the theologians that you are, I'm sure many of you are very well aware of the extra-biblical accounts pertaining to the Great Deluge. It's quite fascinating to read these other ancient sources that depict an extremely similar event... sometimes too similar! Which makes it all the more exciting since it can't just be coincidental (in Atrahasis, two animals of each kind are brought on an ark, in Gilgamesh, doves are sent out to search for land, etc).

I see that a previous question has been asked about "How does the Noah's Ark narrative relate to the Gilgamesh flood account," and it has quite extensive answers that are certainly helpful, but I am curious to know if there is an existing venn diagram or chart of some sort out there that compares/contrasts the details from the Genesis Flood with the Giglamesh and Atrahasis flood. If you happen to know of one, could you kindly point me in that direction?

I am teaching a class on how to analyze these details, and how these details may bespeak a different agenda, purpose, message for each of these narratives. I especially want to demonstrate that even though there are many similarities that the Genesis Account seems more divine (consequence of wickedness) in purpose rather than practical (because the humans are loud and obnoxious). I think there are other key elements which would elevate the divinity of the Genesis flood (I think it can be said that Genesis adopted some aspects of these narratives, but ultimately adapted it to fit God's message), but I would like to refer to all-encompassing charts that compares and contrasts these floods narratives in order to perform the biblical hermeneutics and textual-criticism I so desire.

In short, is there a chart of venn diagram. Or do you have bullet points from all three? What's your take on Genesis appropriating the story and tweaking it to convey God's message? (or perhaps that last questions is a whole other ball park).

Comment: Related: [What are the similarities and differences between the Genesis cration account and other creation stories of the time](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/1252/what-are-the-similarities-and-differences-between-the-genesis-creation-account-a/20436#20436) - while this answer was closed as too broad, it was asking for a comparison of 7-12 texts. The flood narrative has much fewer related texts, and this Q limits answers to 2.

Comment: Also related: [How credible is the theory that Enki and Ninhursag influenced Genesis 2 and 3?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/13115/how-credible-is-the-theory-that-enki-and-ninhursag-influenced-genesis-2-and-3/13222#13222)

Comment: This does seem off topic as posited but I would love to see the Venn diagram when you have it completed!